# Sturm-Liouville Problem: Find Eigenfunctions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for eigenfunctions of the Sturm-Liouville Problem:

$y'' + \lambda y = 0$

With conditions:

$ y'(0) = 0$
$y'(\pi) = y(\pi)$

I found that assuming $\lambda \le 0$ implies $y = 0$.

Supposing $\lambda > 0$, we have:

$y = A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

$y' = -A\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + B\sqrt{\lambda}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$

The first condition implies:

$B\sqrt{\lambda} = 0$

$B = 0$

From the second condition:

$A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) + B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) = -A\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) + B\sqrt{\lambda}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)$

$A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) = -A\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)$

$\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) = -\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)$

Now I am looking for values of $\lambda$ which satisfy the above equation (hopefully there are infinite such values). Then the corresponding eigenfunctions will take the form $y = \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$. The problem is that I don't know how to find $\lambda$.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You basically get an equation $x\tan x  = \text{const}$. It doesn't have an analytical closed form, you need to approach numerically, or in the form of an infinite series. It is, however, a very common case when finding solutions to wave equations, and the behaviour is well known (higher eigenvalues are almost the same as for the standard case of a closed boundary condition, lower are different). See graphical solutions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the problem of discontinuities, I think that it could be simpler to consider that we search for the zero's of function
$$f(u)=u \sin(u)+\pi \cos(u)$$
Since the $n^{th}$solution $u_n \sim n \pi$, we can develop $f(u)$ as a Taylor series around $n \pi$ and use series reversion to get
$$u_n=n\pi-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{\pi }}{n^3}+\frac{-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2}{\pi
   ^2}+\frac{4}{3 \pi }}{n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$
The table below reports the value of the approximation as well as the exact solution obtained using Newton method.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.17838691503 &  2.17672257444 \\
 2 & 5.78574357602 &  5.78574088629 \\
 3 & 9.09209064323 &  9.09209060673 \\
 4 & 12.3166266163 &  12.3166266170 \\
 5 & 15.5080904222 &  15.5080904229 \\
 6 & 18.6829616076 &  18.6829616079 \\
 7 & 21.8483365278 &  21.8483365279 \\
 8 & 25.0077712358 &  25.0077712358 \\
 9 & 28.1632437482 &  28.1632437482 \\
 10 & 31.3159417771 &  31.3159417771
\end{array}
\right)$$
Back to $\sqrt \lambda \pi=u$, this would give
$$\lambda_n=n^2-\frac{2}{\pi }+\frac{2 \pi -3}{3 \pi ^2 n^2}-\frac{10-10 \pi +2 \pi ^2}{5 \pi
   ^3 n^4}+\frac{225-150 \pi +23 \pi ^2}{45 \pi ^4 n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^8}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your equation has infinitely many solutions. It can be written as $\cot x=-x/\pi$ (just call $x=\sqrt{\lambda}\pi$, and you need positive solutions. There are infinitely many intersections, one for each branch of the cotangent. The only way to solve it is numerically, you can use Newton's method, bisection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt \lambda \pi=u $

We have to numerically solve $$ \tan u=\frac{-\pi}{u}$$

There is no closed form solution. Asymptotic solutions are $ u_k= k \pi$ which are used as seed {starting) values in iteration like in numerical procedures of Newton-Raphson.

[image: Transcend. Equn]
There are an infinite number of intersections/ solutions/roots as seen in the graph. First approximate iterated positive value is

$$ u_1\approx 2.17672$$

Other deired values can be obtained by variation of CAS specific commands.

Comment: Yes, thank you corrected typo,